# How to Get the check box checked value from list of checkboxes and call an Ajax function when check box is checked?

Tags: javascript

Hi all, I have the following list of checkboxes like this in my view:

```
         <div class="ProdcutColors" style=" font:11px Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Grande, sans-serif; overflow:auto; height:135px; width:135px; margin:-240px 0 0 528px; border:1px solid #ccc">
<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="Black" value="Black" class="ProdcutColors" />
<label>Black</label>
<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="Red" value="Red" class="ProdcutColors" />
<label>Red</label>
<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="Pink" value="Pink" class="ProdcutColors"/>
<label>Pink</label>
<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="Blue" value="Blue" class="ProdcutColors"/>
<label>Blue</label>
<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="Brown" value="Brown" class="ProdcutColors"/>
<label>Brown</label>
<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="Khaki" value="Khaki" class="ProdcutColors"/>
<label>Khaki</label>
<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="White" value="White" class="ProdcutColors"/>
<label>White</label>
<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="Silver" value="Sivler" class="ProdcutColors"/> 
<label>Silver</label>
<br />  
</div>
```

Now what I want is if a user checks any of the colors I want to call an ajax function passing the value of the checkbox selected. Can anyone tell me how I can do this using JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var container = document.getElementById("ProductColors");
    var checks = container.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var check;

    for (var i = 0; i < checks.length; i++) {
        check = checks[i];
        check.onclick = function () {
            if (this.checked) {
                // Run AJAX function, and use this.value for checkbox value
            }
        };
    }
};
```

This is obviously a Javascript-only solution, and assumes your main div has an id of "ProductColors" - I see in your code that you only set the class - it's just easier to identify it, especially in this case, if you give it an id.

But what it does is find all `<input>` elements in the div (and this assumes the only `<input>` elements are the checkboxes in question - you would have to do more checking if there were other input types next to the checkboxes, like maybe a hidden input), and binds a click handler to each of them. When a checkbox is clicked (since it's a more consistent event than onchange), the handler checks to see if the checkbox state is checked, and runs your code if so...otherwise nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery can do the Job [Check and Uncheck Checkboxes with Jquery](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/check-uncheck-checkbox-jquery/)

Comment: please read the question this is not the answer i am looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this using jQuery,

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ZRHZT/1/

You can use `$('.ProdcutColors').serialize()` to get checked values and send those values through ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You could attach a click handler to each of the check boxes.
Here is a very simple example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
        <head>
           <title>onclickTest</title>
           <script type="text/javascript">
             function RunAJAX(color)
             {
               //Do something...
               alert(color); //proof this works....
             }
           </script>
        </head>
        <body>
          <div>
            <input name="Black" value="Black" onclick="RunAJAX('black')" type="checkbox" /> 
            <label>Black</label>
          </div>
        </body>
      </html>
```

[See Code on JSFiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/tkLwq/10/)